# Why do Newton's laws have to be used only when working with a particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a small understanding of physics but I am not studying the subject.
Whilst trying to model a plane landing in Differential equations (an A-level maths module), we were told that you have to assume that the plane is a particle to be able to apple newtons laws to it, is this the case? If so, why?

Comment: because when Newton was working on his mechanics, he had specific point particle in mind. However, there are cases you can apply Newton mechanics to  more than point particles.

Comment: Freud would've loved your mis-spelling of "apply" when talking about Newton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because any bigger system is made up of small particles and if want to apply Newton's equations to the whole system then we have to apply them on every individual constituent particle, that would be very tedious and lengthy. That's why we use them only for particles.

Answer (score 1):

Because Physics, though a precise discipline, often works with approximations.

In the question you're concerned with the plane can be modelled accurately by thinking of it as a particle. Nothing essential to the question is lost by this approximation.

If we, on the other hand, were concerned about the aerodynamics of the plane, then to approximate as a particle wouldn't do.